# A proposition about cyclic representation in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra, if for an arbitrary cyclic representation $\pi: A \rightarrow B(H)$, we have $\pi(a) \geq 0$, $a\in A$, then can we conclude that $a \geq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state space $S_A$ of $A$ separates points. Doing GNS for each $\phi\in S_A$ we obtain cyclic representations $\pi_\phi$. Then the direct sum $\pi_S=\oplus_{\phi\in S_A}\pi_\phi$ is a faithful representation. So if $\pi_\phi(a)\geq0$ for all $\phi\in S$, then $\pi_S(a)\geq0$ and so $a\geq0$.

Comment: And let $\pi: A \rightarrow B(H)$ be an arbitrary cyclic representation, if $[\pi(a_{i,j})]_{i,j} \geq 0$ in $M_{n}(\pi(A))$, can we conclude $[a_{i,j}]_{i,j} \geq 0$ in $M_{n}(A)$?

Comment: Cyclic is irrelevant. What you need is faithfulness. Without it, the representation is killing things. Even with $n=1$, let $A=\mathbb C^2$, $H=\mathbb C$, $a=(1,-1)\in A$, $\pi$ the restriction to the first coordinate,  which in this case is a cyclic representation. You have $\pi(a)=1\geq0$, while $a\not\geq0$.

Answer (score 3):

Every C$^*$-algebra has a faithful representation that is a direct sum of cyclic representations. So, yes, if $\pi(a)>0$ for every cyclic representation $\pi$, then the element $a$ must be positive.

Take a look at the [wikipedia page for the Gelfand-Naimark Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Naimark_theorem) for further details.

Comment: I only know that every non-degenerate representation is a direct sum of cyclic representations. Is a faithful representation also a direct sum of cyclic representations?

Comment: @Belle-tiantian: Any $*$-representation is the direct sum of a non-degenerate $*$-representation and a zero representation. Consider how $A$ acts on $M = \overline{ \mathrm{span} }\{ \pi(a) \xi : a \in A, \xi \in H\}$ and $M^\bot$.

Comment: @Tom Cooney Thank you~ Tom